# Infinite scroll - data.map not defined with react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to implement infinite scroll from a public API - on reaching the bottom of the page - I am calling the same API with next page . Seeing data.map is not a function - even though I am getting an array - I see network calls with undefined page.
here is my code:
`

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import './App.css';

const fetchUrl =
"https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search?size=small&limit=30";


const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [fetching, isFetching] = useState(false);

  const getData = (page) =>
    fetch(`${fetchUrl}&page=${page}`)
    .then((res) => res.json())


    useEffect(() => {
      getData(page).then((data) => setData(data))
    },[page]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isFetching) return;
    fetchMoreListItems();
  }, [isFetching]);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
  }, []);

  const handleScroll = () => {
   if (window.innerHeight + document.documentElement.scrollTop !== document.documentElement.offsetHeight) return;
   fetchMoreListItems();
  }

  const fetchMoreListItems = () => {
    const dd = getData(page+1);
    setData(dd);
  }
  console.log(data);
  return <div className="cont">
  {data?.map((item, index) =>
      <span key={index} className="cont__item"><img className="cont__item--img" src={item.url} /></span>
      )}
   </div>
}

export default App;
```

`